# How to calculate averages IDs in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have the following data

```
A   B
ID  Time
22  00:20
33  00:30
60  01:30
41  00:20
41  00:30
33  01:00
22  01:00
```

Column A= Id and column B= Time

I want to calculate the average time for IDs and get the following table in Excel

I struggled to do it

```
C   D
ID  Time
22  40
33  45
60  90
41  25
```

Comment: does not look like average to me.  How did you get 80 from `00:20` and `01:00`  that looks like the sum of minutes.

Comment: You could do this with a pivot table, btw.  Just format the output as `[mm]`

Comment: For 22, for example; 00:20= 20; 01:00= 60, averag=40, sorry I will fix it

Comment: Thanks Scott, can we do it using excel function?

Comment: do you have the unique ids listed or do you need to get that too.  If so a pivot table is the best way to go.  If you have the list then use AVERAGEIFS() and format the output correctly.

Comment: I have unique ids list. =AVERAGEIFS(B2:B8,A2:A8,22), give me only for 22, how I can get automatically for all

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: What version of Excel=2016

Comment: Then you do NOT have the `UNIQUE` function. Do you have a unique list of ID's?  If you do, just use `AVERAGEIF` as suggested by others. If not do an internet search for how to generate it using formulas (which is **not** simple) or use a pivot table.

Comment: Read again. I did **not** recommend `AVERAGE`. Merely trying to help you find a solution. And my guess is that you were downvoted because of the reason cited on the downvote arrow:  "*... does not show any research effort*"

Comment: Seems there is a language problem. *Effort* means showing what **you** tried to solve your problem **before** you posted here. And based on the information you presented in your question, the solution by @basic works fine here.  If you are not able to figure out how to apply his solution to your data, I'd suggest you use a pivot table, which will also provide your desired result, and might be easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Make sure you are using the right formula and have the number format as general.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the unique IDs in column C, and want the average on column D, and row 1 has the titles, you could use this formula in cell D2:

=averageifs(b$1:b$1000, a$1:a$1000, d2)

It means "Average the number in column B if what is in column A matches D2".

Fill down the formula.

Then select column D, press Ctrl-1 (with the numbers on top of the letters) to go to format, and in "General" type [mm].

Comment: Thanks, I got all  "01" which does not make sens

Comment: Sorry. You need it in seconds. [s] (an s between brackets) should do it.
I assumed your format was h:mm. It must be mm:ss.

Comment: Or you could display it as integers. Just multiply the result by 24 * 60 * 60 (24 hours, 60 minutes per hour, 60 seconds per minute).

=averageifs(b$1:b$1000, a$1:a$1000, d2) * 24 * 60 * 60

And then select the whole column and press Ctrl-Shift-1 and then remove the extra zeroes.

Comment: Could you help me to get it?

Answer (score 0):

`AVERAGEIF` is enough:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A;D2;B:B)
```

[image]

Cell format `[mm]`

Comment: interesting, but is it  way to automaticity group ID ? This is because I have 30 group, but I showed only 4

Comment: @user330 To get unique ```ID```, use ```=INDEX($A$1:$A$100;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($A$1:$A$100)/(COUNTIF($B$1:B1;$A$1:$A$100)=0);1))```. Adjust ranges accordingly.

Comment: Not sure why the Index... does not work for me select only column A